# WCF Web Service: Upload a file, Process that file, Download that processed file back

Tags: wcf, c#-3.0

I can handle the process that file part, but before I go crazy, has someone built a simple wcf service & client (running under windows services or IIS) that I can use to upload a file, and download that file back? with the fewest lines of code? (C# or VB)

compression & encryption would be cool, but i'll layer that on later!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this fairly easily.  The service contract would probably look like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileService
{
  [OperationContract]
  byte[] ProcessFile(byte[] FileData);
}
```

The encryption part could be handled natively by WCF using transport level security.  I don't believe that WCF supports compression directly, but you could add that using the GZipStream class.

I have not built a file handling service as you describe, but I have built a service that handles byte array data that is passed back and forth between a WCF client and service.  It works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Depending how much time the processing takes, you might be better off using two methods in order to avoid running into timeout issues.

Also, I agree with Igor, you should use streams and not byte[]. Otherwise you will probably run into OutOfMemory Exceptions.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileService
{
  // returns a Guid which you can use later to request the processed files
  [OperationContract]
  Guid SendFileToProcess(stream streamedFile);

  [OperationContract]
  Stream GetProcessedFile(Guid fileId);

  // use this to poll whether the service has finished processing
  [OperationContract]
  bool IsFileProcessed(Guid fileId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WCF transport in streamed mode or/and long-running active object pattern.
Please, follow this [article](http://www.koolzers.net/en/us/articles/long-running-active-object-part1.aspx) for more details or contact me.