# How do I upload a file, process it and return a result file in a single request to a REST WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, rest

I need to implement the following scenario in a REST service implemented in WCF:

- the user submits a binary file and a set of parameters
- the server consumes the file, does some clever work and generates a binary output file
- the user retrieves that binary result file

and all that is done in a single operation from the client perspective.

[It's pretty easy in a non-REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310062/wcf-web-service-upload-a-file-process-that-file-download-that-processed-file-b/310955#310955). How do I do that in a REST service? Where do I get started?

Comment: What type of client application do you have? How do you consume the service?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: I have nothing at the moment and I need to be able to write client programs for as many platforms as possible, so the solution must be as interoperable as possible.

Comment: I made a test at home with posting and returning byte[] as well as Stream and it worked without problem.

Comment: Are you sure you looked for an answer?  I've seen this question addressed several times on StackOverflow.  The only tricky part is you need to enable TransferMode Streamed to be able to send the file up.

Comment: @Darrel Miller: The problem is I'm currently in the phase when I know very little on the subject and don't quite get what is good REST service implementation, so I'm afraid of choosing something fatally wrong. So I searched over SO and I think that I couldn't find an equivalent question for REST services.

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gblock/archive/2010/11/24/streaming-over-http-with-wcf.aspx) is a blog post on how to do it. Here is another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[wcf]+[rest]+upload+file) with a search that will show other related questions with examples.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is that the `XMLHttpRequest` object doesn't support file upload.
So common work arounds are using Flash or another plugin for uploading a file. Or uploading the file using an `IFrame`.

There are many plugins that automate the process, for example
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

The server part is not that difficult.

Your `Request` will have a `Files` attribute which contains the uploaded files. Save the files, and return whatever you want in the Response.

Check out the example in the above stated plugin for dealing with the response on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Since your linked question is not directly about streaming over HTTP you can of course send byte arrays in REST service. Here is example of service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    byte[] GetByteData(byte[] data);
}
```

Data will be send as base64 encoded string. Example of send message:

```
<base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">QmFzZSA2NCBTdHJlYW0=</base64Binary>
```