# How do I return a struct containing binary data from a WCF REST service?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, rest

I have to implement the following scenario:

- the client sends a request to a WCF REST service providing a set of parameters and a binary file to process
- the service gets the file, processes it and produces a result binary file
- the service has to return some structure that contains a "success/fail" processing status, an error message if any, and if there was no error - the result file

In a SOAP service I'd just return something like the following:

```
class ProcessingResult {
public:
    bool IsFailed;
    string ErrorMessage;
    byte[] ResultData;
};
```

and the middleware would properly serialize this over the wire, then the client proxy (produced by parsing WSDL) would deserialize it and the client would be happy.

How do I desing something similar in a WCF REST service?

Comment: Why did you repost your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711811/how-do-i-upload-a-file-process-it-and-return-a-result-file-in-a-single-request-t instead of modifying the original one?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: That's another question. I need to design the datatype appropriately, not a general idea of how that request could be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same in REST service. Here is the service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    ProcessingResult ProcessData(byte[] data);
}

public class ProcessingResult
{
    public bool IsFailed { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public byte[] ResultData { get; set; }
}
```

All byte arrays will be send as base64 encoded string. Example of request message:

```
<base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">QmFzZSA2NCBTdHJlYW0=</base64Binary>
```

Example of response message:

```
<ProcessingResult xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestService">
  <ErrorMessage>String content</ErrorMessage>
  <IsFailed>true</IsFailed>
  <ResultData>QmFzZSA2NCBTdHJlYW0=</ResultData>
</ProcessingResult>
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. Will a WCF service also expose the xml schema?

Comment: @sharptooth: WCF service exposes description (WSDL + schemas) only for SOAP services. In WCF 4.0 you can use new Help page feature to show some description of REST service with message samples (samples I posted in answer are from help page).